# Is distributivity sufficient to define composition?

Tags: functional-equations, binary-operations

Function Composition has the property of distributivity:

$$(f\star g)\circ h = (f\circ h)\star(g\circ h)\;\forall f,g,\star \in\{+,-,\times,\div\}$$

I was wondering if these properties uniquely define composition.

Intuitively, this makes sense. For example:

$$(x\mapsto x^2)\circ f = (I\times I)\circ f = I\circ f \times I\circ f = f^2$$

and a similar process could be defined for any function.

But does this work when functions cannot be easily defined in terms of elementary operations?

Comment: To compute the composition easily as suggested you would benefit from an Hamel basis for the space of functions http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schauder_basis (see related concepts section)

Comment: So what you are saying is if this basis consists of elementary functions, then all functions can be defined elementarily, so this definition works?

Comment: If you know the Hamel basis, then you can express any function as a finite linear combination of functions and this would simplify the computation. Otherwise you can try to use a Taylor series, but this could yield infinite countable calculations.

Comment: I see. But then composition would have to be defined to be distributive on the basis.

Comment: Left distributivity (your first condition) is certainly a property of composition, but right distributivity is most certainly not!
$$(x\mapsto x^2)\circ ((x\mapsto x)+(x\mapsto x)) \neq ((x\mapsto x^2)\circ (x\mapsto x))+((x\mapsto x^2)\circ (x\mapsto x)). $$
The left side is $x\mapsto 4x^2$. The right side is $x\mapsto 2x^2$.

Comment: Whoops. OK, I'll fix that. Any thoughts on whether left distributivity is sufficient?

Comment: So to reformulate the question: Let $A$ be a ring. Assume $\odot$ is a binary operation on the ring $A^A$ of functions $A\to A$ such that left-distributivity with (pointwise) $+,-,\times$ holds. Does it follow that $\odot = \circ$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your conjecture is wrong. Let $q\colon A\to A$ be any map and define $f\odot g=f\circ q\circ g$. Then 
$$ (f\star g)\odot h=(f\star g)\circ (q\circ h)=f\circ(q\circ h)\star g\circ(q\circ h)=f\odot h\star g\odot h$$

Comment: OK. Thanks. Could adding another property uniquely define composition?

Comment: @k_g Of course $\circ$ is associative and my $\odot $ in general is not. But I am unsure if demanding associativity would be enough - composition is so very specific.